# Applying symbology to Folium (Leaflet) polygon layers

Tags: qgis, python, leaflet, folium

I am trying to create a Folium map in Python that includes multiple polygon and line layers. I would like to be able to change the symbology of each layer to differentiate it from the others. I've tried to use the style_function, but that didnt seem to work. Is this possible?

```
style = {'fillColor': '#f5f5f5', 'lineColor': '#ffffbf'}

folium.GeoJson(prop_bnd_pth, name='Property Boundary', style_function=lambda x: style).add_to(map)
folium.GeoJson(stands_pth, name='Stands', style_function=lambda x: style).add_to(map)
```

I understand that both of the folium.GeoJson functions call the same style, but neither of them change in the map. They have the default blue symbology.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919669/folium-geojson-style-function-not-working-as-i-want

Comment: That was actually the post that I followed when trying to apply the symbology in the first place.